Two animated gifs in Photoshop exporting with different number of frames
I'm trying to export two animated gifs in Photoshop 2020 (21.1.3) that are, as far as I can tell, the same length. Both consist of a series of smart objects clipped to raster shapes, and use the video timeline. They appear to have exactly the same framerate and number of frames on the video timeline.
First gif:

Second gif:

However, when I export them through Save for Web and Devices, they each have a different number of frames (16 vs. 25, shown at the bottom of the panel).
First gif:

Second gif:

The smart objects were created on multi-layer video timelines in their own files, converted into smart objects, and duplicated into these files; they're mostly comprised of still image frames, so it seems possible that one is removing duplicate frames somehow. However, if I open up the individual smart objects, the lengths/framerates are all the same as the "master" files.
Is there a setting I'm missing or an action I've done that could cause these two gifs to export to different lengths?
The content of the gifs is mildly NSFW so I'm avoiding a full screenshot of the Photoshop window, but if more detailed screenshots of a menu/setting/area are useful I can add them in as needed.

AFAIK GIF frames can have variable frame times. Obviously this can alter the meaning of 30fp in that some of those 30 frames might be the single frame held for longer time rather than 30 actual frames. I may have missed it in your description, but do they have the same run time?
